# How to create an array with hours and minutes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

i am trying to create a time array, something like:

```
1:00
1:15
1:30
1:45
2:00
2:15
...
```

here is my code, what it does is that it starts the time from current time upwoards:

```
var timeArray = [];
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours();
var m = d.getMinutes();

for (var i = h; i <= 24; i++) {
   for (var j = m; j <= 59; j++) {
       if (j % 15 === 0) {
            j = j === 0 ? '00' : j;
            if (i >= 12) {
                timeArray.push((i - 12) + ':' + j + ' PM');
            } else {
                timeArray.push(i + ':' + j + ' AM');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that is `m` is over `46`, like `var m = 50;`, then the array goes empty because `j % 15` doesn't get 0 no more.

an ideas how to fix this?

thanks

Comment: Should `h` be `hours` and `m` be `minutes`?

Comment: Maybe I'm mising the point, but instead of checking if the element is divideable by 15, just increment J by 15 in each loop:   for (var j = minutes; j <= 59; j = j + 15

Comment: @FrisoKluitenberg im not sure how that would work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If what you want is an array ["1:00", "1:15", ...] then why not just build that? It has nothing to do with "hours" and "minutes", only with "getting some obviously sequential numbers" right:

```js
cost arr = [];
for (let i=0; i < 24; i++) {
  for (let j=0; j < 4; j++) {
    arr.push(`${i}:${j === 0 ? `00` : 15*j}`);
  }
}
```

Done. Find your current time nearest a 15 minute block:

```js
const d = new Date(),
      h = d.getHours(),
      m = 15 * Math.floor(d.getMinutes() / 15),
      stamp = `${h}:${m === 0 ? `00` : m}`;
```

And just reorder the timeslots:

```js
const pos = arr.indexOf(stamp);
let timelist = [];
if (pos > -1) {
  timelist = [
    ...arr.slice(pos),
    ...arr.slice(0,pos)
  ];
}
```

Comment: i want it to keep track of the current time. Basically the time should start from whatever time is now until 24 hours

Comment: okay? So build this array, then find the array entry that is closes to your current time, and reorder the array (remove slice(0,current-1) and concat it to the end). The array itself *still* has nothing to do with hours and minutes =)

Comment: there is still an issue, if now is `3:40 PM` the array will start from `3:00` instead of `3:45`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var timeArray = [],
    d = new Date(),
    h = d.getHours(),
    m = d.getMinutes(),
    meridiem = ['AM','PM'];
for (var i = h; i < 24; ++i) {
    for (var j = i==h ? Math.ceil(m/15) : 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        timeArray.push(i%12 + ':' + (j*15||'00') + ' ' + meridiem[i/12|0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: if `m = 50` and time is `3:43` your array starts from `4:00 PM` rather then `3:45 PM`

Answer (score 3):

A one liner:

```js
const arr = Array(24 * 4).fill(0).map((_, i) => { return ('0' + ~~(i / 4) + ': 0' + 60  * (i / 4 % 1)).replace(/\d(\d\d)/g, '$1') });
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is a bit long-winded, but it also gives you the associated time value which could be useful in some cases.

```js
const getTimeBlocks = () => {
    const minutesInDay = 1440;
    const timeBlocksArr = [{ timeString: '12:00 AM', timeValue: '0' }];
    for (let i = 30; i <= minutesInDay - 30; i += 30) {
        const halfHourInLoop = i / 60;

        let formattedBlock = String(halfHourInLoop);
        const hour = formattedBlock.split('.')[0];
        const minute = i % 60 === 0 ? '00' : '30';
        formattedBlock = `${hour}:${minute}`;

        const today = new Date();
        const timeString = new Date(
            today.getFullYear(),
            today.getMonth(),
            today.getDate(),
            Number(hour),
            Number(minute),
        );
        timeBlocksArr.push({
            timeString: timeString.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' }),
            timeValue: formattedBlock,
        });
    }

    return timeBlocksArr;
};

console.log(getTimeBlocks());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it simpler by using JavaScript Date API and by a simple trick.

In loop all you need is to add 15 * 60 seconds (one quarter of an hour) to timestamp and print. 
Only calculate the closest full time (11:57 -> 12:00) at the beginning, then add as much quarters as you need.

Please see the code:

```
var date, array = [];
date = new Date();

// Here we will find the closest time
// If it's 13:09 we'll iterate to 13:15 and stop
//
// We'll iterate fifteen times in the worst case scenario
while (date.getMinutes() % 15 !== 0) {
    date.setMinutes ( date.getMinutes() + 1 );
}

// A whole day has 24 * 4 quarters of an hour
// Let's iterate using for loop
for (var i = 0; i < 24 * 4; i++) {
    array.push(date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes());
    date.setMinutes ( date.getMinutes() + 15);
}

console.log(array);

// Now in Poland it's 18:10 so the result is an array of 96 elements 
// ["18:15", "18:30", "18:45", "19:0", ... "17:30", "17:45", "18:0"]
// As you may noticed, there is a need to format date when it's a full hour.
// We have 18:0 but we expect 18:00. This will be more understandable for users.
// We can open another discussion to find the best way to do that ;)
```

Comment: this answer is very incomplete

Comment: It's simple..
1. Get current timestamp
2. Find the closest quarter
3. Start adding to your array. The next date will be previous date + 15 minutes. Timestamp is a time in seconds - this is why I wrote 15 * 60.

Comment: cool, I wasn't suggesting you may not have had a viable approach but without a proper explanation the answer itself was poor quality compared to most

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the inner loop (`j`) starts at `m` variable, and that probably is not zero at most times of the day. So for the first loop of `i` that is ok. But for next loop you want that to be zero. You can fix that by assigning that `m` variable to zero at the end of the `i` for loop.

And try not to mix the variables that are for calculations (integers) with the ones you use for formatting the time (strings). You are doing that for `j` in here:

```
j = j === 0 ? '00' : j;
```

Here is the code I'd use (I also fixed the AM for 12 midnight and skiped most iteration of j by simply incrementing by 15 instead of by 1):

```
var timeArray = [];
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours();
var m = Math.ceil(d.getMinutes() / 15) * 15;

for (var i = h; i <= 24; i++) {
  for (var j = m; j <= 59; j += 15) {
    var mf = j === 0 ? '00' : j;
    var hf = i >= 12 ? (i - 12) : i;
    var amPm = i >= 12 && i < 24 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    timeArray.push(hf + ':' + mf + ' ' +  amPm);
  }
  m = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var timeArray = [];
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours();
var m = d.getMinutes();

for(var i=0; i< 24; i++){
    for(m = (m + 15 - m%15)%60; m < 60; m = m + 15){
        timeArray.push(h + ':' + m);
    }
    h = (h+1) % 24;
    timeArray.push(h + ':' + '00');
}

console.log(timeArray);
```